# Excel: finding matching names between columns when names are part of longer string in one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one column/list filled with appointment information (column A), and another separate column/list of clinician names ( column C).  I am interested in simplifying column A down to just a clinician name(its match from column C).  Is there a method/approach which could be used to find matches in column A and C, and then list them in column B?

Column A has about 1,100 rows, Column C about 200 rows(names).

Thank you in advance for your time and consideration!

Column A
Appointment Info
08/06/2018 @ 10:00 AM
(240 min)
AA MH/PHD Testing CLC=IP
Est Patient
CID/PID:08/06/2018
(Wait: 0 days)
Scheduled on: 6/13/2018
By: Suzie Chapstick
Comments: F107
No Show Count:4
Miles to Clinic: NA

08/08/2018 @ 12:00 PM
(120 min)
AA MHC/CHOL-Harpman EVAL
New Patient
CID/PID:07/03/2018
(Wait:36 Days)
Scheduled on: 7/3/2018
By: Legg, Stanley
Comments: Per MHC
NoShow Count: 7
Miles to Clinic: NA

08/06/2018 @ 09:00 AM
(180 min)
AA MHC/PSY-Stinger Intake
New Patient
CID/PID: 6/7/2018
(Wait:60 days)
Scheduled on: 7/6/2018
By: Finkbeiner, Maria
Comments: Per MHC
NoShowCount: 3
Miles to Clinic: 16

Column C
Brown
Duncan
Finley
Harpman
Stinger

Comment: Can you post a copy/ image examples of the data sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Clinicians,MATCH(1,MATCH("*"&Clinicians&"*",A1:A10,0),0)),"not found")
```

Here are my results:

[image]

I gave the Clinicians a range to help the readablity,  the same could be done with Col A.  I'd also suggest the clinicians be on a separate tab altogether.

The First "not found" has no "hits" in the clinicians list, the second and third are opposite blank cells.

Hope that helps

Good Luck

Comment: I moved my clinician list to a new worksheet and using your formula as a guide entered the following formula: =IFERROR(INDEX('Clinicians list'!$A$1:$A$250,MATCH(1,MATCH("*"&'Clinicians list'!$A$1:$A$250&"*",$A$1:$A$926,0),0)),"not found").  The good news is I am not receiving an error message.  The bad news is, when I copy and paste the formula I am getting "Not Found" for every appointment.  Most likely I am just not understanding your formula correctly.  Hopefully it is an obvious error you can assist me with.

Comment: My apologies, I wasn’t clear in that this is an array formula, so after you enter it, press ctrl+shft+enter, the formula shiuld then have {} around it. Also, you can still use the named rang method for referencing the clinicians list, even if on another sheet.

Comment: Update: I just tried this by moving the 'clinicians' named range to another sheet (ctrl-x;ctrl-v) and also with "long form" `Sheet3!$A$1:$A$4`, both worked as expected, however if using the "long form" make sure the cell references are absolute references `$`, otherwise your cell references will "shift".  `={IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet3!$A$1:$A$4,MATCH(1,MATCH("*"&Sheet3!$A$1:$A$4&"*",A1:A10,0),0)),"not found")}` or `={IFERROR(INDEX(Clinicians,MATCH(1,MATCH("*"&Clinicians&"*",A1:A10,0),0)),"not found")}` 

Good luck

Comment: It's working!!  Thank you, Jbowman.  This is a huge help and should save us lots of time.  Can't thank you enough.

Comment: Certainly.  I couldn't remember how yesterday..to click the check mark.