# Formula for finding parent child relation in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have the data in the following format in excel for which the parent is given and below the parent given is its respective child.

```
Parent   abc
1        def
1        fsdfd
1        sfd
1        sdf
2        fdsf
Parent   xyz
1        gsd
1        gfh
1        hgf
2        kkn
```

**I want the formula in excel for getting the data in parent child format like below such that the parent comes instead of the numbers**

```
abc abc
abc def
abc fsdfd
abc sfd
abc sdf
abc fdsf
xyz xyz
xyz gsd
xyz gfh
xyz hgf
xyz kkn
```

Comment: There's absolutely no logic in your excel... parent ID's are not unique, the same ID's refer to multiple other parents... I don't see how you are able to achieve this, other then replacing parent by the value on the right hand side and filling it downwards until you reach the next parent.

Comment: I understand your concern , but we have got such data from client side in unstructured text format , so we are converting it to structured format now .

Comment: @bo-oz  its not possible to do it in your method , because there is around 4 lakh such records .

Comment: You should do a search on here - there are many similar questions and this is but one : https://stackoverflow.com/q/51621277/4961700

Comment: What do the numbers under Parent denote? And does your data actually have the text "parent" in it? Or does '2' denote that the next item is a parent?

Comment: @jeffreyweir  yes it has parent in it , you can ignore the 1s and 2s

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Your data would have to start at Row 2 for this to work. Based on your example provided, copy this formula into col C. Once you have the "Parent" values, you can paste those values into Col A.

```
=IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(A2)),B2,C1)
```