# INDEX MATCH the correct formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use the `INDEX(MATCH())` formula to find part or parts of a string then copy an abbreviated name into the cell I need. I have tried to get this to work but I must be missing something or just not understanding.

Here is the layout:

- Sheet **DigAlm** in cell C2 has something like this "UNIT 903 CONTROL POWER ALARM"
- Sheet **Alm_Abbr** I have two columns setup,

  - Column A has a longer string like "CONTROL POWER"
  - Column B has the abbreviated name like "CPOWER"

This is the formlula that I have in cell I2:

```
=INDEX(Alm_Abbr!B:B,MATCH("*"&C2&"*",Alm_Abbr!A:A,0))
```

The result is an Error -

> Did not find value '*UNIT 903 CONTROL POWER ALARM*' in MATCH evaluation.

Any ideas? Help please.

As a side note I do have something that works, but I don't think it's the ideal way.

```
=IF(C2="","",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*CONTROL POWER*",C2)),"CPOWER",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*FAIL TO START*",C2)),"FAIL TO START",
```

and it keeps going with all possible variables. So it is quite long.

Comment: Your DigAlm C2 appears to be all upper case, but your Alm_Abbr lookup value is upper/lower.  is it possible to convert Alm_AbbrA:A to upper case

Comment: Thank Jbowman, converted them all to upper and still the same result. I have also tried adding all the pieces together in the same sheet just to make sure it's not something with sheet to sheet. If I take out the "*"&C2&"*" and use "*CONTROL POWER*" it will work and place my abbr. name in.

Comment: `MATCH("*"&C2&"*"...` will match `"*UNIT 903 CONTROL POWER ALARM*"`. MATCH is not FIND

Comment: Take a look at my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621277/excel-finding-matching-names-between-columns-when-names-are-part-of-longer-stri/51622170#51622170

Note this uses an array formula, so it must be entered with Ctrl+shft+enter,  
hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much @Jbowman `=IFERROR(INDEX(Alm_Abbr!$B$2:$B$26,MATCH(1,MATCH("*"&Alm_Abbr!$A$2:$A$26&"*",DigAlm!C3,0),0)),"NOT FOUND")` works